# php - output echo'd contents in browser while script is running?

Tags: php

Does anyone know how to output stuff I echo to a browser while the script is running?

I have a long loop that I'd like to output a string after every run of the loop, kind of like a  progress bar, does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`ob_flush()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) function:

```
ob_start();
//echo stuff...

ob_flush();

//echo more stuff...

ob_flush();
```

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it didn't do anything, script still executes fully then outputs everything at once to browser.

Comment: @Joe, It is probably working fine, but your browser probably isn't displaying it to you.  Check it with a packet sniffer, or Fiddler or similar.  Also, some servers won't push that data to you when `ob_flush()` is called.  It is up to the server, not PHP, to do this.

Comment: @Joe so how did you fix it?

Comment: @Joe How did you fix this problem?